# Quais os requistos para criar um app para windows usando ionic?

Tags: ionic, windows, apache-cordova, build

Criei um app para android usando o ionic, queria pegar esse mesmo app e buildar para pc, quais os requisitos e como fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o Ionic necessite do VS2010, na página https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/vs/older-downloads/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fduckduckgo.com%2F role e escolha a opção 2010, baixe ela e instale.

No Windows 10 é necessário ativar o modo desenvolvedor.

Depois no seu projeto execute:

```
ionic cordova build windows
```

Ele vai instalar o `cordova-windows` (https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows) sozinho.

Para instalar (se não tiver usado o build) e executar também:

```
ionic cordova run windows
```

Comment: mas eu preciso baixar todos aqls arquivos, ou so um arquivo?

Comment: Caro @Ronkzinho "você" não baixa nada, quem baixa é o próprio comando do ionic, ele não vai só baixar o que é estritamente necessário, mas como vai gerar os arquivos necessários diretamente em sua máquina e depois é só navegar até a pasta `platforms/windows/` e lá vai ter o arquivo do projeto se desejar abrir no visualstudio (não estou falando do VScode);

Comment: Então eu dou o build usando o visual studio, ou o prompt de comando

Comment: @Ronkzinho é no prompt mesmo, vc navega até a pasta do teu projeto e executa o comando. Nem tinha como ser no VisualStudio, pq o projeto para VS só existe depois que executar os comandos e o NPM baixar as dependências :) ... eu citei acessar pelo VS apenas acaso precise ajustar algo do VS mesmo no projeto. O caminho é o mesmo de fazer para android, mas o platform é windows.

Comment: Mano, esta retornando esse erro: localdodomeuprojeto\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio..Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild: Command failed with exit code 1

Comment: @Ronkzinho você tem que instalar com "Universal Apps", no instalado do VS tem a opção, seleciona, instala e então o build vai funcionar.